# ember, ember-validations match password and confirmation

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-app-kit

I've been successful in modifying the default classes and the negative class values to make sure that my ember-validations appear the way I want them to on load. Now, I'm diving into ember-validations. One of the validator routines I'm having little success with is the match: property. Here's the code from my controller:

```
    userLoginPass: {
        presence: { message: " password required" },
        match: { property: { "userRegPassConfirm" } }
    },
    userRegPassConfirm: {
        presence: { message: " confirm password required" },
        match: { property: { "userLoginPass" } }
    },
```

However, neither field barks on mis-match between them. Something is missing. Anyone had experience with this?

Here's the doc that's giving me problems: https://github.com/lcoq/ember-validations#match

Many Sincere Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the answer is a two part process which includes making sure the confirmation field is labelled whateverConfirmation in addition to the confirmation property like so:

```
password: {
  confirmation: true,
     presence: {
       message: ' password required'
     }
   },

passwordConfirmation: {
  presence: {
    message: ' please confirm password'
    }
  }
```

as seen on the ember-validations documentation page:

https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations#confirmation

Answer (score 0):

You should define the validations object on your controller (or model) as follows:

```
validations: {
    userLoginPass: {
        confirmation: {
            message: 'Your message here.'
        }
    }
}
```

And then put an `{{input userLoginConfirmation}}` within your template.

Comment: interesting, i was able to find the answer by chatting brian in #emberjs, he said to use match. i used match without the "match" property, (as you have also shown) even though that's the way it's documented here: https://github.com/lcoq/ember-validations#match

Comment: That library is not maintained anymore. This one is: https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations, but this one doesn't have a 'match' validator.

Comment: oops. linked to the wrong one... no wonder... here it is: https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations#confirmation